# What is the meaning of low level access to in c?

Tags: c

I just started programming in C and i am stuck with a phrase that the main feature of C **include low level access to memory** anyone can explain what does that mean.

Comment: Post your code in order to get some help.

Comment: It means that the C syntax allows you to access memory directly using pointers. In this way the C language allows you to write code that are very close the machine code of your system. Hence it is called low level.

Comment: It also means C doesn't come with trailing-wheels. That puts all the responsibility on YOU, the programmer, to ensure you use only the memory you have valid access to. If you allocate 2 bytes, there is nothing stopping you from attempting to write 50 bytes at that address. That fundamental access to memory without safeguards is what makes C so blazingly fast, but it also put all the responsibility on the programmer to use that memory access correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers run in machine code (zeroes and ones).  If you open up a program in a hex editor, or look at any hardware manual which talks about communication, you will see lots of symbols in the range `[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]`, which is machine code in base-16 rather than base-2.  It is tough to write a program in machine code!  Think of this as ground 0; every bit you write is going to be run on the computer hardware.

That machine code is a series of instructions; on most computers like a desktop or laptop they are [instructions based on x86](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-5477/ennbz/index.html), and those bytes have been assembled from those instructions.  The instructions are written, aptly, in assembly code!  Both these topics are a very brief introduction and if you're interested read more on them, but essentially they allow access to registers and hardware directly.  Again, each step is being run directly, but it's slightly more abstract as it allows us to start using the whole alphabet!  It has to be compiled though to run on a processor.

C isn't assembly code, and it's mostly readable in human form.  C essentially an older language named B with type system (int, char etc) - and B is basically friendly syntax for assembly.  This is why you can skip type in a lot of C statements and it defaults to `int`.

What C doesn't do though is:

- memory management
- object-orientated programming
- coroutines
- advanced type features

Pointers allow you to directly modify memory, and essentially you would like to do is possible (in both good and bad ways).  A lot of C methods compile to a handful of assembly instructions, and although it offers a huge ability, it requires a lot more work than a higher-level language - many of which might compile to C before assembly.

Think of it as a pyramid; the desert is the ground/machine code, the base is assembly which is hard and strong but takes a lot of work, and C sits above it, still at a low level and taking a lot of work but it's a lot easier than doing the base!  Compare them to Java and C# which sit above these at a higher-level, and that should answer the question.  It's an abstract concept which doesn't mean much in reality for the language.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer would be: C has pointers.

A medium length answer is: you have relatively easy/free access to memory trough pointers.

A longer answer with an example:

```
int i = 42; // i is an integer (usually 4 bytes)
int *p;  // p is a pointer to an integer (it's not pointing to anything now)
p = &i;  // make p point to the integer x, so now x and *p are "the same"
// and you can do crazy stuff like this
char *p1; // p1 is a pointer to an char (char is 1 byte)
p1 = ((char*)p) + 1; // now p1 points to the address one above p (i.e. the second byte of x)
*p1 = *p1 + 1; // this will effectively add 32 to x (if my in head math is correct)
```

This example is quite contrived, and you shouldn't do stuff like this. You shouldn't worry about not knowing what "low level access to memory" means, and try to learn C. Eventually, when you understand C and it's pointer mechanism, you'll probably understand what the book meant by "low level access to memory".

Answer (score 1):

In a low level language like C, the programmer can more or less directly manipulate RAM. RAM is a device on your computer that basically contains bytes at addresses, similar to mailboxes and box numbers. Just as you might put mail in mail box 5, you can put 15 into address 2000, or something similar.

A common example of low level access is that you might tell C to make a new integer somewhere in RAM, where you can then modify it, and delete it later.

In other languages you might be familiar with, this management is done behind the scenes and you may never know where your program data is put, but in C you have almost total control.